# Changing nicknames in discord.py throwing an error

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm setting up a discord bot with `discord.py` when trying to change a nickname, whenever I try I'm thrown an error

I've tried quite a few things but every time I am thrown an error saying that Client does not have an attribute `change_nickname`, I've looked and this is the only thing I've seen that could do it.

```
client = discord.Client()

await client.change_nickname( message.author, " testthing")
```

is my code (i excluded the code above it)

```
  File "nicknamechange.py", line 19, in on_message
    await client.change_nickname( message.author, " testthing")
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'change_nickname'
```

that is the error I get thrown.

I've tried a lot, looked at the documentation but I haven't found any solutions, and it is very infuriating.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using discord.py 1.0, then note that there have been some [API changes](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/migrating.html#models-are-stateful). In particular, the `change_nickname` function was removed, and you now have to call the `edit` function on some member, i.e.,

```py
await message.author.edit(nick="testthing")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now i am getting a forbidden error, saying that I don't have permissions, even though i do, here is the error:
        raise Forbidden(r, data)
    discord.errors.Forbidden: FORBIDDEN (status code: 403): Missing 
    Permissions

Comment: This is hard to solve without any further information, but as you said, it seems to be a permission problem. Try manually logging in as the bot and changing the nick of some user. If that doesn't work either, you don't have the correct permissions set up yet.

Comment: Thanks, how do you directly log into a bot?

Comment: You're right, there seems to be no way to directly log in as the bot. Can you show the bot permissions overview?

Comment: On the discord the bot has administrator permissions. @PhillipF